# Bluetooth Firmware bug

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, firmware

I have an Acer Aspire VN7-571G-56EF running 16.04, upgraded from 14.04.5 and have never been able to get the bluetooth to work. rfkill list all shows everything is fine:

`rfkill list all`

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

BUT...

```
uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

gives me:

```
Linux compooper 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e08e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e092 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy (MTP)
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    [    8.926314] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
    [    8.927640] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [    8.933129] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [    8.933134] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [    8.933146] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [    9.443693] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [    9.443696] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [    9.443700] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [    9.464267] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [    9.464276] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [    9.464282] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [    1.126114] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
    [    7.571059] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    bluetooth 520192  31 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
```

Clearly I'm getting a "firmware bug", but I'm not sure what to do to fix it. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks, @Jeremy31. I followed your instructions and things are better, but I get the following fail, bug and firmware crash messages now:

```
    Linux compooper 4.8.0-040800-generic #201610022031 SMP Mon Oct 3 00:32:57 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e08e]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e092 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    [   10.767266] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
    [   10.767280] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   10.767589] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   10.767591] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   10.767603] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   10.876730] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000200.bin
    [   10.876733] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x200 build 0x299, firmware rome 0x200 build 0x111
    [   10.957650] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000200.bin
    FAIL? -> [   12.877045] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send body at 4 of 1859 (-32)
    FAIL? -> [   12.878461] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to access otp area (-32)
    [   13.235593] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   13.235594] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   13.235598] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   23.281766] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000200.bin
    [   23.656660] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   23.656665] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   23.656676] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [ 7932.541075] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00000200.bin
    [ 7932.541077] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x200 build 0x299, firmware rome 0x200 build 0x111
    [ 7932.595265] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00000200.bin
    BUG? -> [    1.890954] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
    FAIL? -> [    9.519461] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    FAIL? -> [    9.519479] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
    [    9.541919] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
    [   10.876733] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x200 build 0x299, firmware rome 0x200 build 0x111
    CRASH? -> [ 7929.883576] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid n/a)
    [ 7929.883965] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
    [ 7929.886178] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware register dump:
    [ 7932.541077] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x200 build 0x299, firmware rome 0x200 build 0x111
    bluetooth             548864  51 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
    rfkill                 24576  14 bluetooth,acer_wmi,cfg80211
    crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

Any thoughts?

Hi @Jeremy31 and @LiveWireBT!

So after a few months of using the new kernel I have gone back down to 4.4. Sadly 4.8 and above gave me constant problems with my mouse, wifi, hibernation, suspension, etc. Basically I could connect at home, close my lid and go to work, but then it wouldn't see the work network - only the home network would show in the list of available wifi networks and the computer never really suspended. It just kept going with the lid closed. Downgrading from 4.9 to 4.8 returned suspension, but still the wifi issues. Upgrading to 4.10 was just a nightmare, so i quickly went back down to 4.8. I've realized that having BT isn't as important as having a stable system that's not going to throw problems at me every day, but would still like to get the BT back since i use it for work conferencing. So guess I'll just have to ask to fix the 4.4 kernel.

Thanks to everyone for you help, though!

Comment: It should be supported in Ubuntu 16.10 with the 4.8 kernel as kernel support was just added in July.  Ubuntu could fix the 4.4 kernel to support it but you would need to file a bug report against linux see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I have to run out the door and will look into this more later today, but do you know if the 4.8 kernel will work with 16.04.1?

Comment: It should work unless you have  hybrid graphics.  It is possible to patch the 4.4 kernel but it would have to be done after every kernel update.  I might check Pilot6's PPA to see if he has fixed this already using dkms

Comment: Kernel 4.8 is already available in 16.04: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge

Comment: Sweet onion chutney! Thank you, @Jeremy31! After all this time I finally have bluetooth audio and can use my headset. Nothing against you, @LiveWireBT, Jeremy was just the first to answer and I was able to install 4.8.0-040800 before I got your message, but thank you too!                                 Though I oddly get a crash message now - see above.